# sbt: running a scala project's main class directly

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm using sbt to build a simple Scala project which I want to run through the JVM directly (that is, not via `run` which executes it through scala's MainGenericRunner).

How can I do this? The options I've seen (`run`, `run-main`) all execute the class through `MainGenericRunner` instead of directly. I can see that run/{Fork, Scala}.scala have code for doing things just like this, but I'm not sure how to use it to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: What is wrong with the MainGenericRunner?

Comment: It uses its own class loader beneath Java's top level one which causes problems with one of my dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [plugin for sbt](https://github.com/typesafehub/xsbt-start-script-plugin) that creates a script to run your Scala program, i.e., not having to use `sbt run`

Comment: I still want to work within sbt, but I want to use some kind of `run` which executes my scala program directly on the JVM, not via scala's `MainGenericRunner`.

Answer (score 0):

You can fork the process using  `fork := true` in your settings. This will launch the app in a new JVM instance.

Comment: With `fork := true` a process is executed in a new JVM but with a line like `java ... scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner ... MyClass`, whereas I want to execute MyClass directly with a line like `java ... MyClass`.