# With SBT, how do I a specify an alternate project root other than the current directory for running a main class?

Tags: sbt

Normally SBT looks for the build files at `./build.sbt` and `./project/Build.scala`. Is it possible to specify an alternate project root, so I can build a project not in the current working directory? I'm looking essentially for an equivalent to `mvn -f /path/to/pom.xml` but the docs have not provided me with any obvious answers.

(I should note that I want to do this at runtime rather than compile time. Essentially, I want to use `sbt run-main` to run arbitrary classes from my project, since I **hate** manual classpath wrangling. For various boring reasons I may need to do this from arbitrary location since the code may need the working directory to be something other than the project directory, so using `cd` might not do what I want. It's so trivial in Maven - I just assumed, perhaps unfairly, that there would be a simple equivalent in SBT)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I discovered from [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8167204/1711188), the [sbt-start-script](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-start-script) plugin is a better tool for this than `sbt run-main`. You can simply run `sbt stage` and you get an invocation script, with classpaths resolved, at `target/start`. According to the documentation, it needs to be run from the build root directory for inter-project dependencies to work, but for my simple use cases, this doesn't seem to be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have something like this. I have project definition at `X/build.sbt`, `X/MyOtherDefinitionWithSpecialThing/build.sbt`, `X/MySuperPublishConfig/build.sbt`.

But my point of view  to the problem is opposite. Instead of specify location of `./build.sbt` and `./project/Build.scala` I specify location of path to resources. The result is the same. It looks like:

```
sourceDirectory <<= (baseDirectory) (_ / ".." / "src")

target <<= (baseDirectory) (_ / ".." / "target")
```

This is allow to create single project with multiple definitions. This is worked with nested/hierarchical projects. But I use symbolic links (Linux OS) for hierarchical projects.

There is a file tree of one of my SBT plugins. Multiple build definitions and only one `src/...`

```
.
|-build.sbt
|-project
|---project
|-----target
|-------...
|---target
|-----...
|-project-0.11
|---build.sbt
|---project
|-----project
|-------target
|---------...
|-----target
|-------...
|-project-0.12
|---build.sbt
|---project
|-----project
|-------target
|---------...
|-----target
|-------...
|-...
|-src
|---main
|-----scala
|-------org
|---------...
|---sbt-test
|-----...
|-target
|---...
```

If this not solution of your problem please elaborate why you don't want use 'cd' command ;-)

-- For the updated use case:

I use shell wrapper and I have symlink to this one in every SBT project:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
here=$(cd $(dirname "$0"); pwd)
if [ ! -e "${here}/build.sbt" ]
then
  echo build.sbt lost
  exit
fi
cd ${here} 

LOCAL_BUILD=true sbt-0.12 "$@"
```

I simply write `/path/to/my/project/sbt 'show name'` for example or `/path/to/my/project/sbt run-main` in your case.

Comment: Looks like a great solution for some use cases - thanks. However, it's not quite what I'm looking for in this particular case. I've now clarified the question to explain what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Updated. SBT launcher is strictly bonded to the directory structure. This is very verbose for hierarchical projects or projects with plugins.

Comment: Thanks, but it's still using 'cd'. If the code needs to run from an arbitrary point in the file system -- say, because it expects data files to be in the current working directory, this still won't work. (This is probably bad design on the part of the project, but if that's true, then it's equally bad design on the part of SBT)