# How to Add Environment Profile Config to SBT

Tags: sbt

In Maven you can have Profiles, which can set up a build configuration for different environments.  For example DEV, QA, UAT, PRODUCTION

In order to support continuous integration, there must be a way to tell SBT which environment to run against.

how to set up for different environments in SBT.  For example DEV, QA, UAT, PRODUCTION?

thanks

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600119/with-sbt-how-do-i-a-specify-an-alternate-project-root-other-than-the-current-di/16761503#16761503?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do this by creating a custom configuration.

```scala
val ProfileDev = config("dev") extend(Runtime)
val ProfileQA  = config("qa") extend(Runtime)

val root = (project in file(".")).
  configs(ProfileDev, ProfileQA). // add config here!
  settings( 
    name := "helloworld",
    ....
  ).
  settings(inConfig(ProfileDev)(Classpaths.configSettings ++ Defaults.configTasks ++ Defaults.resourceConfigPaths ++ Seq(
    unmanagedResourceDirectories += {baseDirectory.value / "src" / configuration.value.name / "resources"}
  )): _*).
  settings(inConfig(ProfileQA)(Classpaths.configSettings ++ Defaults.configTasks ++ Defaults.resourceConfigPaths ++ Seq(
    unmanagedResourceDirectories += {baseDirectory.value / "src" / configuration.value.name / "resources"}
  )): _*)
```

You then place your config file in `src/dev/resources` and `src/qa/resources`, and it should be part of your classpath when you say `dev:run` or `dev:package`. Here's a quick test:

```
object Main extends App {
  println(xml.XML.load(this.getClass.getResource("/config.xml")))
}
```

Comment: I've added this to my Build.scala, but when running e.g. dev:package I'm just getting "No such setting/task". Any advice?

Comment: What's the `Build.scala`? Do `show ivyConfigurations` to see the configs in a project. I bet you haven't added the `dev` config or haven't executed `inConfig`.