# How to deploy playframework project with profile

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I have a project using [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.com/) and I'm looking for a way to deploy on multiple platforms with different configuration profile.

Maven would achieve this using the following ways:

1. Create [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Profiles).
2. Using [Maven Resources Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/)'s [`copy-resource`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/copy-resources-mojo.html), I can copy some xml file (like `hdfs-site.xml`) from different directory, and relative to a series of platforms.
3. The profile can be specified from the commandline via `-P` and I can run `package` command: `mvn -P A package`.

How can i build a project like this used Play? Like `hdfs-site.xml` and `hbase-site.xml`, it should be able to copy files to classpath.

Comment: I rewrote your question a bit. I hope I got all the details right.

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of [How to Add Environment Profile Config to SBT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193795/how-to-add-environment-profile-config-to-sbt)

Comment: See my answer to [How to Add Environment Profile Config to SBT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20573422/3827). You can add custom configuration and achieve similar effect.