# sbt-native-packager bashScriptExtraDefines profiles

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

I want to create some kind of "branding" for scala application using sbt-native-packager.
The idea is to configure two profiles in sbt (aprofile and bprofile) and when calling specific 
target it defines correct configuration file to be used when starting application.

Two configuration files

```
conf/a.config
conf/b.config
```

I want to package application using following keys

```
sbt aprofile:stage
sbt bprofile:stage
```

Sbt-native-profile defines

```
bashScriptExtraDefines += """addJava "-Dconfig.file=${app_home}/../conf/app.config""""
```

Now the question is how to create those two profiles in sbt to define bashScriptExtraDefines property accordingly. I am trying to use https://stackoverflow.com/a/20573422/289043 somehow, however I don't know how to correctly overwrite bashScriptExtraDefines.