# How to handle multiple build targets, e.g. dev, test, main?

Tags: maven, sbt

I'm currently migrating from Maven to SBT, and I'm struggling to understand how I can handle multiple build targets (dev, test, train, prod etc).

For example, I have a `persistence.xml` that looks like this:

```
<properties>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="${db.connectionURL}"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="${db.username}"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="${db.password}"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="Oracle10"/>
</properties>
```

With Maven, it was really easy to handle this using profiles.

I've already tried what was suggested here for SBT, but I'm not having any success with that approach.
[How to Add Environment Profile Config to SBT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193795/how-to-add-environment-profile-config-to-sbt).

Also, using that approach I would need a new directory for each new environment. I just think that there has to be a better way to handle this kind of setup using SBT?

Comment: What exactly did you mean by "not having any success"?

Comment: I did not see any output except what was already in my resources catalog (no error or anything like that). And as I mentioned, I was hoping that there is some better solution that doesn't force me to add 5 directories if I have 5 targets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** Use `ivyConfigurations` to add custom configs and `resourceGenerators` to process files per environment.

All credits goes to [Eugene Yokota](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3827/eugene-yokota) for the answer to [How to Add Environment Profile Config to SBT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17193795/1305344). There are some modification that make the solution of mine...*cough*...*cough*...slightly better.

The following `build.sbt` defines two new configurations - **dev** and **qa**. It also defines `resourceGenerators` per configuration that effectively gives a way to access what configuration the new resourceGenerator executes in:

```
val Dev = config("dev") extend Runtime

val Qa  = config("qa") extend Runtime

ivyConfigurations ++= Seq(Dev, Qa)

// http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Howto/generatefiles.html#resources
lazy val bareResourceGenerators: Seq[Setting[_]] = Seq(
  resourceGenerators += Def.task {
    val file = resourceManaged.value / "demo" / "myapp.properties"
    println(s"Inside ${configuration.value}")
    val contents = s"config=${configuration.value}"
    IO.write(file, contents)
    Seq(file)
  }.taskValue
)

inConfig(Dev)(Defaults.configSettings ++ bareResourceGenerators)

inConfig(Qa)(Defaults.configSettings ++ bareResourceGenerators)
```

Inside the new resourceGenerator you can do whatever you want and the per-configuration processing is possible with the `configuration` setting that gives you the name of the configuration:

```
> show dev:configuration
[info] dev
> show qa:configuration
[info] qa
```

Now when you execute `show qa:resources` you'll see that there are two files generated with `target/scala-2.10/resource_managed/qa/demo/myapp.properties` with the content that's specific to a configuration:

```
> show qa:resources
Inside qa
[info] List(/Users/jacek/sandbox/envs/target/scala-2.10/resource_managed/qa/demo/myapp.properties, /Users/jacek/sandbox/envs/src/qa/resources)
```

The trick now is to use the resourceGenerator to meet your needs and since you're in Scala code you can do whatever you want - just use `configuration.value` as the qualifier for a configuration-specific code.

Say, you want to use a `qa`-specific properties file in the standard `src/main/resources` directory. Just know where the value is bound to (what configuration and setting the value comes from). It's just `compile:resourceDirectory`.

```
> show compile:resourceDirectory
[info] /Users/jacek/sandbox/envs/src/main/resources
```

Just use `resourceDirectory in Compile` whenever you need a "stable" (*aka* configuration-fixed) value like `src/main/resources`.

```
val props = (resourceDirectory in Compile).value / s"${configuration.value.name}.properties"
println(s"Read files from $props")
```

With the above lines you'd get:

```
> show qa:resources
Inside qa
Read files from /Users/jacek/sandbox/envs/src/main/resources/qa.properties
[info] List(/Users/jacek/sandbox/envs/target/scala-2.10/resource_managed/qa/demo/myapp.properties, /Users/jacek/sandbox/envs/src/qa/resources)

> show dev:resources
Inside dev
Read files from /Users/jacek/sandbox/envs/src/main/resources/dev.properties
[info] List(/Users/jacek/sandbox/envs/target/scala-2.10/resource_managed/dev/demo/myapp.properties, /Users/jacek/sandbox/envs/src/dev/resources)
```

Comment: Hi, there do you now have a well documented documented tutorial about this ?

Comment: How much do you need? What do you miss currently?

Comment: Thanks. Is this approach supported by Intellij Idea? E.g. is there the ability to chose the configuration?