# Multiple SBT Configurations should be exclusive, but they all activate at the same time - why?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have defined a minimal build.sbt with two custom profiles ‘dev’ and ‘staging’ (what SBT seems to call Configurations). However, when I run SBT with the Configuration that was defined first in the file (dev), both Configuration blocks are executed - and if both modify the same setting, the last one wins (staging).

This seems to break any notion of conditional activation, so what am I doing wrong with SBT?

For reference, I want to emulate the conditionally activated Profiles concept of Maven e.g. `mvn test -P staging`.

SBT version: 1.2.1

`build.sbt`:

```
name := "example-project"
scalaVersion := "2.12.6"
...

fork := true

// Environment-independent JVM property (always works)
javaOptions += "-Da=b"

// Environment-specific JVM property (doesn’t work)
lazy val Dev = config("dev") extend Test
lazy val Staging = config("staging") extend Test
val root = (project in file("."))
  .configs(Dev, Staging)
  .settings(inConfig(Dev)(Seq(javaOptions in Test += "-Dfoo=bar")))
  .settings(inConfig(Staging)(Seq(javaOptions in Test += "-Dfoo=qux")))
```

Command:

```
# Bad
sbt test
  => foo=qux
     a=b

# Bad
sbt clean dev:test
  => foo=qux
     a=b

# Good
sbt clean staging:test
  => foo=qux
     a=b
```

Comment: have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26217862/how-to-handle-multiple-build-targets-e-g-dev-test-main ?

Comment: @pedrorijo91 I have seen that SO post, and while the resource filtering looks interesting, it still uses the same SBT Configuration concept as my example, so I don’t see how they have managed to make only one environment apply. What am I missing here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that despite of the `inConfig` usage you're still setting `javaOptions in Test`, i.e. in the `Test` config. If you remove `in Test`, it works as expected:

```
...
  .settings(inConfig(Dev)(javaOptions += "-Dfoo=bar"))
  .settings(inConfig(Staging)(javaOptions += "-Dfoo=qux"))
```

(also `Seq(...)` wrapping is unnecessary)

Now in sbt:

```
> show Test/javaOptions
[info] *

> show Dev/javaOptions
[info] * -Dfoo=bar

> show Staging/javaOptions
[info] * -Dfoo=qux
```

You can achieve the same result by scoping each setting explicitly (without `inConfig` wrapping):

```
  .settings(
    Dev/javaOptions += "-Dfoo=bar",
    Staging/javaOptions += "-Dfoo=qux",
    ...
  )
```

(here `Conf/javaOptions` is the same as `javaOptions in Conf`)

Comment: Gave this a go and sure enough the right Java system properties show up in each environment *in SBT*. Bizarrely, however, when I print System.getProperties *in the test code*, environment-independent javaOptions are present, but the environment-specific javaOptions are missing. Now that is odd.

Comment: Turns I had forgotten to add the boilerplate `.settings(inConfig(Dev)(Defaults.testSettings))` and `.settings(inConfig(Staging)(Defaults.testSettings))`. Once I added those, and made your change, the tests then ran and saw the correct javaOptions.

Comment: I'm glad that you found the reason.